# What does "its" refer to?

Tags: meaning

General speaks to Edward about Foriegn Intellingence Service:

> General: I see this as America's eyes and ears. I don't want it to
> become **its** heart and soul. So I told the President, for this to work,
> there's gonna have to be some kind of civilian oversight.

What does "its" refer to?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Its" refers to *America*.

> I see this as America's eyes and ears. I don't want it to become America's heart and soul.